# Multiple is_page() in page.php

Tags: php, functions, pages

I'm trying to add multiple page IDs into an if else statement. This is my code so far:

```
if ( is_page(ID) || is_page(ID) ) { 
    get_header('header_alt'); 
} else { 
    get_header(); 
}
```

I tried a few other solutions found on google, yet it always only works on the initial page after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass an array of IDs to [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) instead of using multiple `is_page`:

```
if( is_page( array( 11, 22, 33, 44 ) ) ) {
    // Your code
}
```

Also, if you are using it in a loop, you should consider this note:

> Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop,
>   is_page() will not work. In order to call it after The Loop, you must
>   call `wp_reset_query()` first.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Jack Johansson's answer,  this also works for page slugs.
For example:

```
if( is_page( array('news', 'work', 'about', 'contact' ) ) ) {
// Your code
}
```